# Sort an array using NSSortDescriptor without use of any key?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I have an array **appd.arrOfDictAppProd**, in there is a a key **Price** which is a String value. But i want to sort this array by Price value. So I fetch Price key from **appd.arrOfDictAppProd** array and convert Price to String to Int, then make an NSMutableArray **newarray** without any key. I want to sort this using **NSSortDescriptor** this without use of any **Key** because in my newarray have no key. My code is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i<appd.arrOfDictAppProd.count; i++) {
    NSString *price_Value = [[appd.arrOfDictAppProd objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"price"];
    int price_IntValue = [price_Value intValue];
    NSLog(@"int value of prices:%d",price_IntValue);

    NSNumber *num = [NSNumber  numberWithInteger:price_IntValue];
    NSLog(@"number-%@",num);
    [newarray addObject:num];

}
NSLog(@"price array:%@",newarray);

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor =[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"num"
                                                    ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray1;
sortedArray1 = [newarray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

When i run my program, in the **newarray** I have 14 values but these are same, that is 3.

Comment: Fix your `for` loop. You are getting the same object over and over which is why `newArray` contains 14 identical values.

Comment: @rmaddy. can you tell me how to fix for loop ..plz help

Comment: Replace `indexPath.row` with `i`.

Comment: yes. i already changed value..and now i gate 14 different values that are in array.@thanks dear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly I've missed the point but it sounds like you're massively overcomplicating things.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [appd.arrOfDictAppProd sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
    @[
        [NSSortDescritptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"price.intValue" ascending:YES]
    ]];
```

If you wanted to create `newarray` regardless — or just without your manual loop — then go with:

```
NSArray *newarray = [appd.arrOfDictAppProd valueForKeyPath:@"price.intValue"];
```

---

The mechanism relied upon here is key-value coding. I've also built upon the specific way that `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` implement key-value coding.

`-valueForKey:` and `-valueForKeyPath:` are provided by `NSObject`. Ignoring special cases and fallbacks, an object will respond to the former by returning the value of that property as an object — amongst other things it'll automatically convert built-in numeric types to `NSNumber`s. The latter will traverse object hierarchies, as e.g. `object.property1.property2` will request `object`, then request `property1` from `object`, then request `property2` from `property1`.

You can therefore use `[stringObject valueForKey:@"intValue"]` to access the `intValue` property on `stringObject` and then have `NSObject` package it up into an `NSNumber`.

`NSDictionary` has an implementation of key-value coding that will look into the dictionary for an appropriate value unless it's prefixed with an `@` to mean that you want information *about* the dictionary, not *from* the dictionary. Because your key name is a string that doesn't begin with an `@`, `valueForKey:` therefore ends up calling `objectForKey:`.

Therefore the sort descriptor with key `price.intValue` on an array of dictionaries will ask each dictionary for the value for key `price`. The dictionary will decide to call `objectForKey:`. It'll get a string back. It'll call `intValue` on that string and get an `int` back. It'll then wrap that into an `NSNumber` and compare the numbers for all dictionaries to decide the ordering.

`NSArray` implements `valueForKey:` and `valueForKeyPath:` by calling the corresponding method on each item in the array in turn and then returning the array containing all those results. So you can use key-value coding as a way to map results to a certain extent.

Answer (score 1):

Because `newarray` is just a (mutable) array of `NSNumber`s, and `NSNumber` implements the `compare:` method, you can call

```
[newarray sortArrayUsingComparator:@selector(compare:)];
```

immediately after the for-loop. You don't need sort descriptors.

Comment: Why is this being upvoted? It won't help. The OP states that `newArray` contains the same number over and over. Changing the sort won't help. The bug is in the `for` loop.

Comment: @rmaddy.sorry for being late to response.And i need help right now.

Comment: @rmaddy..you are right.bug in For loop,.I Ask how to Fix For loop.Thanks